# ACF: using load_field to prepopulate field with a posts feat image url

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to create a custom field that when the editor loads, the pages/posts featured image url would be populated in the post if it exists. The ACF Docs for the load_field function all revolve around using selects and not a normal text field.

I have tried to do something similar like so:

```
    function my_acf_load_field( $field ) {
        $file = get_post_meta( $attachment_id, '_wp_attached_file', true );
        $field['feat_image_file_name'] = $file;

        return $field;

    }
    // name
    add_filter('acf/load_field/name=feat_image_file_name', 'my_acf_load_field');
```

The page doesn't populate with the value (even though the post does have a feat image assigned). Any help to point me in the right direction would be great. Thank you.

Comment: I would post this question over on the ACF forums as they are super active over there. When you get an answer, you could update your question here as well.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution thanks to another developer helping me. Solution below:

```
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * AUTO-POPULATE ACF Field with FEATURED IMAGE URL PATH
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

function getThumbURL()
{
    $myfile = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ));
    $finalresult = "";

    if(count($myfile) > 0 && is_string($myfile[0]))
    {
        // get the domain site url and strip it out of the result for relative path only
        $domain = get_site_url(); 
        $finalresult = str_replace($domain, '', $myfile[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        // Placeholder image if no feat image assigned
        $finalresult = '/dir/to/placeholder/img.jpg';
    }
    return $finalresult;
}

function my_acf_update_value( $value, $post_id, $field  ) {
    $value = getThumbURL();
    return $value;
}

add_filter('acf/update_value/name=feat_image_file_name', 'my_acf_update_value', 10, 3);
```